# naive_bayes.default error in argument y in r

Tags: r, naivebayes

naive_bayes.default gives error with y as :

"y has to be either a factor or character or logical vector"
here y are names in the dataset.

```
results <- naive_bayes(data1[,14], data1[,1], prior=data1[,16])
```

default: naive_bayes(x,y,prior)

where data[,14] are marks, data[,1] are names,data[,16] are category in my dataset.

Pls clarify the problem. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without seeing the actual data, take a look at `class(data1[,1])` - if it isn't `factor`, `character` or `logical` then you have a problem.

Comment: It is a character vector

Comment: Can you provide `dput(head(data1))` ? That will be the only way to conclusively determine what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
results <- naive_bayes(data1[,14], as.character(data1[,1]), prior=data1[,16])
```